# How can i get "Table of content" from PDF file and save it to the tree struct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, aspose, tableofcontents

[image: I mean this as table of content]

I really need to get table of content from a pdf file.with Aspose.pdf.dll in C# asp.net

My questions are:

1. What page is it(for each item)?
2. What is the the text of each page
   for each item in table of content?

Comment: you mean i show you my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose.Pdf.Generator namespace only supports the feature to create TOC while generating new PDF and Aspose.Pdf for .NET does not support the feature to manipulate TOC in existing PDF file. However for the sake of implementation, the requirement is added in issue tracking system as **PDFNEWNET-34836**. Once the new feature becomes available, we would be able to get the information associated with each item in TOC.

*PS, My name is Nayyer and I am Evangelist/Support developer at Aspose.*